# Mostrar mensaje tras apertura de Form

Tags: c#, windows-forms

estoy realizando una aplicacion donde tras la ventana de logeo, si eres un nuevo usuario, se va a ejecutar un tutorial para mostrar el uso de la misma.
El problema es que se ejecuta un metodo del segundo formulario donde se muestran messagebox antes de que se cierre el form de logeo, actualmente lo tengo con este codigo;

```
private void abrirInicioJuego()
    {

        fb.timerRecursos();
        FormInicial pi = new FormInicial(fb,tutorial);     
        pi.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
```

Este código se ejecuta en el formulario de logeo abriendo el formulario inicial de la aplicación.

```
    private void PaginaInicioJuego_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       FormTimers ft = new FormTimers();
       ft.recupearUltimaConexion(id_partida);
       ft.calcularDiferenciaDeTiempos(id_partida);

        //Comienza a ejecutarse el tutorial
        if (tutorial && this.Visible)
        {
            EmpezarTuto();
        }
    }
```

En el load del formulario inicial ejecuto un método (EmpezarTuto(); ) Pero todos los mensajes que contiene ese método aparecen antes de que se muestre siquiera el formulario, antes de cerrarse el form de logeo.

Comment: Intenta meter el código que muestra el tutorial en el evento `Form.Shown`. Este evento se lanza una vez el formulario de muestra en la pantalla

Comment: No conocía ese evento, gracias , pero aun estaría mejor darle un poco mas de retardo.

Comment: En ese caso, puedes por ejemplo crear un timer en el evento `Shown`, y en el Tick del timer mostrar el tutorial y desactivar el timer

Comment: Buenísima idea, había pensado en hacer un `Thread.Sleep(1000);` pero creo que no es para nada buena práctica. Muchas gracias !!

Comment: El `Thread.Sleep` bloquearía el UI durante todo ese tiempo. Todo depende de si necesitas que el formulario responda o no, pero yo tiraría por el timer la verdad.

Comment: Como echo de menos el metodo `Invoke("Nombre metodo", tiempo retardo)` que proporciona Unity :(

Comment: Tienes opciones para simular eso. Si quieres te añado alguno en una respuesta

Comment: Puedes utilizar un Task.Delay: `Task.Delay(tiempo_retardo).ContinueWith(t => EmpezarTuto());`

Comment: Te lo agradecería, nunca está de mas aprender algo nuevo.

Comment: Asier Villanueva, el problema al usar lo que dijiste es que los mensajes que muestro los he creado en un form personalizado, y los invoco de esta manera;             `mens.mensaje = "Bienvenido....";
            mens.ShowDialog(this);` al pasarle `this`, tiene que ser con el hilo principal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El evento [`Form.Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx) se lanza cuando se empieza a cargar el formulario. Por eso es posible que el tutorial aparezca antes de que el formulario aparezca en pantalla.

Es mejor usar el evento [`Form.Shown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown(v=vs.110).aspx), que se lanza la primera vez que el formulario es mostrado en pantalla.

Si lo que necesitas es un retardo, tienes varias opciones. Por un lado, puedes  crear un [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) en el evento `Shown`, y en el `Tick` del `Timer` mostrar el tutorial y desactivar el `Timer`.

Puedes usar tambien un método anonimo, algo similar a lo siguiente:

```
System.Threading.Timer timer;
timer =  new System.Threading.Timer((obj) =>
         {
               EmpezarTuto();
               timer.Dispose();
         }, 
         null, 1000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
```

Otra opción es usar la clase [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx), con los métodos [`Delay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay(v=vs.110).aspx) y [`ContinueWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t => EmpezarTuto());
```

<sub>Tienes mas información sobre métodos retrasados en [esta pregunta de StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/545533/579895)</sub>